# Java generics casting

Tags: java, generics

How please works following generic casting?

```
private <T, N> N send(final T request) {
    final String serviceUrl = "someUri"

    try {
        return (N) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceUrl, request);
    } catch (final SoapFaultClientException e) {

    }
}
```

When I call this private method like this:

```
MyReq request = new  MyReq();
MyResp response = send(req);
```

How this method casting this object into MyResp object? 
What mean this in return type:

> < T, N>

Comment: `<T, N>` means, that the method has two type parameters, named `T` and `N`.

Comment: The return type is `N`. `private ... N`.

Comment: your return type is only `N`. 

`<T, N>` is a kind of initialization of the generic variables. This is the syntax of generic variables initialization.

Comment: <T,N> is not return type but N is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> < T, N>

Is not a return type. N is.

```
private <T, N> N send(final T request)
               ↑
```

You have "choosen" type T by passing MyReq argument. Before returning value of marshalSendAndReceive it is being casted to N type. In your case MyResp.

```
<T,N>
```

just declares that this class/method is generic and you may specify generic input type as well ans output.

Comment: Ok, so (N) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive just casting object into N (MyResp) ok? And why I can't just return N object? Why I need there <T,N> ?

Comment: <T,N> allows you to use send method with any T argument type and expect N type of returned value from the method. **Consider N and T as "variables" that will be initialized when constructing class/using method**. The same method might get String input and return Integer output. But in your case it received MyReq and returns MyResp. That's the point of generics in Java.

Comment: Non-generic version of this method would be:
`private MyResp send(final MyReq request) {
    final String serviceUrl = "someUri"

    try {
        return (MyReq) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceUrl, request);
    } catch (final SoapFaultClientException e) {

    }
}`

Comment: semi-generic:
`private <Z> Z send(final MyReq request) {
    final String serviceUrl = "someUri"

    try {
        return (Z) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceUrl, request);
    } catch (final SoapFaultClientException e) {

    }
}`
Now it may return any type marked as Z while it can get MyReq as input.

Answer (score 0):

The method is parameterized with the generic parameters `T` and `N`. It takes an argument of type `T` and returns a reference of type `N`.

The return type is not `<T,N>`, it is just `N`.

Answer (score 0):

It's about using templates in java similar to templates in C++;

Example:

```
void add(T x, T y){
System.out.println(x+y);
}
```

Above function can be called with either of the following...

```
add(3.0f, 4.5f);
add(2,3);
```

Means, the function is for any kind of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here `T and N` are Generic parameters.

Here the return type is `N` not `<T,N>.`

[Read more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/)